# Notepad++ Reduce this list to just the surnames

Tags: notepad++

I know how to do a few basics of removing characters with replace in Notepad++, but I have quite a complicated list of Chinese surnames and I want to remove everything except the surname itself. Here's a sample of the list.

趙   1   Zhao4   (to return the goods to the original owner; to go away rapidly),
 Chao4 (Wade-Giles), Chew, Chieu, Chu (Cantonese), Chiu

錢   2   Qian2   (cash, coin, money), Ch'ien2 (Wade-Giles)

孫   3   Sun1    (grandson, descendants , MoyGen#41 ), Suen3 [r39]

So all I want left here would be -

Zhao

Qian

Sun

So I guess I'm looking to remove everything before the first English-alphabet letter (Z, Q, S) and then everything from the first number onwards?

I've tried to find cleaner lists but it's difficult for Chinese names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^.*?([A-Za-z]+).*`
- **Replace With:** `\1`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

It literally catches the first sequence of Ascii letters into `\1` and replaces the whole line with this sequence.